# How do I select specific text before a specific character in regex?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to use Notepad++ to select and delete some characters that occur at the beginning of a CSV file I'm working on. the specific data I'd like to remove is anything that follows the opening 13 characters `(123456.123456)`, but before the first `|`.

Data is as follows:

```
167689.010802/PCT|071699.00087|"DATASETNAME"
167689.010803/PCT2|071699.00070|"DATASETNAME"
167689.010804/US|071699.00071|"DATASETNAME"
167689.010805/JP|071699.00073|"DATASETNAME"
167689.010806/CA|071699.00074|"DATASETNAME"
167689.010807/AU|071699.00075|"DATASETNAME"
167689.010808/EP|071699.00076|"DATASETNAME"
167689.010809/CN|071699.00080|"DATASETNAME"
167689.010810/US/CON|071699.00072|"DATASETNAME"
```

As you can see, the data is already `|` delimited. However, not every row is the same. Some contain 2 sets of data, while some contain letters followed by numbers.

What's the easiest way to select this specific data within the set?

Comment: [Search: `^\d{6}\.\d{6}`](https://regex101.com/r/eA7uM0/1)

Comment: @Tushar that would select the first 13 characters in the row, not the data that follows it before the first | character.

Comment: Something like `(?m)^([^/\r\n]{13})[^|\r\n]+(?=\|)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:

```
(?<=^\d{6}\.\d{6})[^|]+
```

If they are always 6 digits, dot, 6 digits at the beginning or:

```
(?<=^.{13})[^|]+
```

if it should match any 13 characters.

It uses positive lookbehind which is called assertion in notepad++ [reference](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions#Multiplying_operators). You assert, that you only want to match characters after certain pattern.

Comment: @sln give us any argument on your statement that a regular expression with a positive lookbehind with `^` at the beginning has a very bad performance.

Comment: Regex1:   (?<=^\d{6}\.\d{6})[^|]+
Options:  < m >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   9
Elapsed Time:    3.28 s,   3279.79 ms,   3279788 µs


Regex2:   ^\d{6}\.\d{6}[^|]+
Options:  < m >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   9
Elapsed Time:    0.81 s,   811.82 ms,   811818 µs

Comment: Give an argument using DFA. as you can implement regex as DFA and it won't be slow.

Comment: I have nothing against dfa, see if notepad convert's to dfa.

Comment: It looks aggressive now, but believe me that I added the previous comment much earlier. Looks like the mobile app doesn't post immediately sometimes

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with a capture group:

```
^(.{13})[^|]+
```

The first 13 characters are captured as the first capture group, and everything else up to the `|` is discarded.

You will need to use the replacement `$1`.

Comment: The dot will also match a pipe character. (btw, I didn't downvote)

Comment: @sln "anything that follows the opening 13 characters" is what the OP said.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. The OP seems a little fixated on 13, yet accepts an answer where the first 13 can't match in some cases, and where  the performance is terrible. People that don't know regex can't pick the right answer. +1 for yours though.